# Uplodify jquery problem with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I'm working in a small project which envolves uplodify. Everything is working good but I have a small problem with a variable and I don't realize where the problem is.

What I'm doing here is splitting the reposone. Then I use the splitted information to create links such as BBCODE for forums and HTML code for websites and append them into textareas.

The problem is that my html_code variable is not working because it has a syntax problem (at least that is what I belive) but I can't find it.

The BBCODE is working great and is being shown in a textarea, but not the HTML.

Below a portion of the Uploadify code I'm using. Please take a look at the html_code variable.

```
'onSelectOnce'   : function(){$('#fileQueue').show();$('#mfstart').show();},
'onAllComplete'  : function(){$('#fileQueue').hide();$('#mfstart').hide();},

onComplete : function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {


aa = response.split('||');
var imurl=aa[0];
var thumb=jQuery.trim(aa[1]);

link_url=''+imurl+'\n';

forum_code='[URL='+imurl+'][IMG]http://localhost/imgsum/uploads/thumbs/'+thumb+'[/IMG][/URL]';

html_code='<a href="'+imurl+'" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost/imgsum/uploads/thumbs/'+thumb+'" border=0></a>';


$('#codes1t').append(link_url);
$('#codes2t').append(forum_code);
$('#codes3t').append(html_code);

}

});
```

thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Can you provide the error message or screen shot for your error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html#html2) function instead of append.

so `$('#codes3t').html(html_code);` should work.

Comment: You're welcome :) (and accept the answer if this what you were looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask )

Comment: the .html() function is always replacing links. For example if I upload 10 images only the latest image link is being showed. Is there any way to fix that ?

Comment: you can use it as a getter as well. So you'll do something like that to append it: 
$('#codes3t').html($('#codes3t').html()+html_code);

Comment: Hum in fact, i was wrong, .append() should work. It's probably coming from your html. See: http://jsfiddle.net/2VRbF/1/ for a working example.
border is a deprecated img attribute, you'd better put some css  like `img{border:0}`. That might come from that.

Comment: @Py your help is much apreciated ! 

NOTE -> Im using textareas not divs to show the links.

Using .append() is working but in DIVs not in textareas. Im 100% sure that this has something to do with the html.

Using .html() also works in DIVs but its not working fine in textareas. If I upload 10 images its only showing the latest uploaded image link. Using the code in your previous reply (not the lastone) solved my problem. Thanks again for your help !

Comment: @Py after testing the srcipt with IE I realised that the html_code is shown inside the textarea, but instead of showing the links code is showing the picture.... I hate IE !

Comment: IE... it's a lot of problem yeah... But nice to see that it worked :)